# Is correct the following definition of $R^n$ valued Sobolev spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^m$  an open. Define the Sobolev space
$$W^{1, 2}(\Omega; \mathbb R^n):=\{ g \in L^2(\Omega; \mathbb R^n) \ : \ D g \in L^2(\Omega; \mathbb R^{n \times m}) \},$$
where $Dg$ is the distributional Jacobian of $g$ (i.e. the derivatives are meant in the distributional sense).
$W^{1, 2}(\Omega; \mathbb R^n)$ is Hilbert with
$$
\langle h, g \rangle_{W^{1, 2}(\Omega;\mathbb R^n)}:=\  \langle h,g \rangle_{L^2(\Omega; \mathbb R^n)} \ +\ \langle Dh,Dg \rangle_{L^2(\Omega; \mathbb R^{m \times n})}.
$$
Here by $$\langle Dh,Dg \rangle_{L^2(\Omega; \mathbb R^{m \times n})}$$ I mean the product component by component of the matrixes $Dh$ and $Dg$.

Is everything correct?

Comment: There are a lot of equivalent inner products on Sobolev spaces but this looks fine to me

Comment: This is indeed the standard definition.

Comment: Thaks then I guessed correctly.